# Erro as.POSIXlt.character ao importar MDB no R

Tags: r, microsoft-access

Olá, procurei essa resposta por toda internet e não achei :)

Estou importando um MDB (Ms Access db) no R Studio (Windows 7 R v32b) usando RODBC porém ao dar o comando sqlFetch estou tendo um erro na importação de uma coluna de data que está em formado dd/mm/YYYY (formato de data brasileiro).

Esse é o código que estou executando:

```
install.packages('RODBC',repos='http://cran.r-project.org')
library(RODBC)
channel <- odbcConnectAccess("db.mdb")
JE <- sqlFetch(channel, sqtable="Table", colnames = FALSE, rownames = FALSE)
```

E esse é o resultado:

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Tentei dar um debug no sqlFetch mas não consigo identificar onde esse erro está ocorrendo. Alguém sabe como editar essa função para corrigir essa falha?

Obrigado!

Comment: Guilherme, talvez você possa carregar uma amostra do arquivo *.mdb, Isto ajudaria a reproduzir o erro e talvez dar uma alternativa como solução.

Comment: tenta usar o argumento `as.is = T`. `JE <- sqlFetch(channel, sqtable="Table", colnames = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, as.is = T)`

Comment: É isso! Funcionou!

Comment: @DanielFalbel, por favor poste o comentário com a solução como uma resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeLouzada se o Daniel não postar coloque a solução você mesmo como uma resposta e feche a pergunta. Pode ser útil para outros usuários.

Comment: @FlavioBarros já coloquei!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tenta usar o argumento `as.is = T`.

```
JE <- sqlFetch(channel, sqtable="Table", colnames = FALSE, rownames = FALSE, as.is = T)
```

Depois você pode converter em data usando `as.Date`.